# PHP exec command prevents echo from working

Tags: php, apache, raspberry-pi3

In this code:

```
session_write_close();
echo "reload";
flush();
//    exec("/etc/init.d/streaminit stop");
//    sleep(2);
//    session_write_close();
//    exec("/etc/init.d/streaminit start");
//    //all we have to do is copy currentView into nextView to trigger a page reload
//    sleep(2);
```

the echo of "reload" works, but if the lines below it are uncommented, nothing is echoed. I have tried many permutations of this and the conclusion is that the `exec` command is preventing the `echo` from working. 
I found some discussion of `exec` causing problems with Apache2, and one person said that `session_write_close()` might prevent the problem. Evidently in this case it doesn't. Are there any known fixes for this? Am I doing something wrong?

(`streaminit` is a shell script that starts and stops the `mjpeg_streamer`. The shell commands are asynchronous (with `&` at the end))

Comment: Scripts in `/etc/init.d` usually need to be run by `root`. Webserver scripts are not generally run by root.

Comment: The scripts are working. It's the `echo` that isn't, and it fails whether placed before or after the `exec`.

Comment: I can't think of any way that `exec` can affect an `echo` that happened before it.

Comment: And the advice about `session_write_close()` also seems specious. `exec` has nothing to do with sessions. `session_write_close()` is needed when you try to run multiple scripts that access the same session, since the second one will be blocked by the session lock.

Comment: @Barmar: me neither, but that's what I'm consistently seeing. Take out the calls to `exec` and `echo` works. Not that it should matter, but the php defines a `Content-type: text/plain` header.

Comment: I'm sure echo works in both cases, but something else is happening to prevent you from seeing the result. Do you really need all those `sleep(2)` calls?

Comment: The `flush()` makes me think you're expecting to see results before the script completes, is that true?

Comment: @Barmar, no, the `sleep()`s were added in a desperate attempt to make this work.

Comment: @Barmar no, again, the `flush()` was another stab in the dark that didn't help.

Comment: Maybe the problem is with that `init.d` script. If you use `exec("echo stop")` and `exec("echo start")`, do you still have the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found this in the documentation for PHP's `exec`: "If a program is started with this function, in order for it to continue running *in the background* (my emphasis), the output of the program must be redirected to a file or another output stream. Failing to do so will cause PHP to hang until the execution of the program ends." The fix:

```
exec("/etc/init.d/streaminit stop > /dev/null 2>&1 &”);
```

For those unfamiliar (like me until a minute ago), this redirects the `stdout` device to `/dev/null`, and the `2>&1` means "send `stderr` output to the same place as `stdout`. Finally, the `&` means "run this command in the background". Works!